# is there a more efficient way to write results from a query in python?

Tags: python, sql-server-2005

[This](http://www.pha.com.au/kb/index.php/Python_-_MS_SQL_Server_Modules#Example_2) is effectively how i'm using _mssql.

Everything works fine, even after i use `fetch_array()`.

The problem is, when I iterate through `fetch_array()`, it takes over ten minutes for 6K rows to be written to the body of an email. This just isn't acceptable.

Is there a better way for me to do this?

EDIT: haven't figured out the best way to copy python code here but here is the crappily formatted code used.

code for writing the email body:

```
    results=mssql.fetch_array()  
    mssql.close()  
    resultTuple = results[0]  
    if resultTuple[1] == 0:  
        emailBody = 'Zero Rows returned'  
    if test or resultTuple[1] != 0:  
        i = 0              
        columnTuples = resultTuple[0]   
        listOfRows = resultTuple[2]  
        columns = []  
        emailBody = ''  
        if test: print 'looping results'  
        while i < len(columnTuples):  
            columns.append(columnTuples[i][0])  
            emailBody = emailBody + columns[i].center(20) + '\t'  
            i = i + 1          
        emailBody = emailBody + '\n'  
        for rowTuple in listOfRows: #row loop  
            for x in range(0, len(rowTuple)): #field loop  
                emailBody = emailBody + str(rowTuple[x]).center(20) + '\t'  
                if test: print x  
            emailBody = emailBody + '\n'
```

Comment: not sure how to profile. What I do know is that the time is not taken up querying the database, but rather while writing my results to the email.

Comment: Could you show us some code of iterating through the results and creating an email?  If I had to make a wild guess, I would say you are probably violating this idiom: "Build strings as a list and use ''.join at the end."  If you keep adding to a string as you go you create a new (and progressively larger) string on each iteration, which runs in quadratic time.

Comment: you're probably right on, steven. You should put this in an answer and i'll post my code momentarily.

Comment: @Ramy: please fix the indentation of your code

Comment: @John, i'd love to. Could you explain how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you show us some code of iterating through the results and creating an email? If I had to make a wild guess, I would say you are probably violating this idiom: "Build strings as a list and use ''.join at the end." If you keep adding to a string as you go you create a new (and progressively larger) string on each iteration, which runs in quadratic time.

(Turned this comment into an answer at the request of the OP.  Will edit to more complete answer as needed.)

**Edit:**

Ok, my guess was correct.  You'll want something like this:

```
email_lines = []
for row in result:
    line = do_something_with(row)
    email_lines.append(line)
email_body = '\n'.join*(email_lines)
```

Comment: could you give me an example of how to use this?

Comment: `'\n'.join('\t'.join(x) for x in listOfRows)`

Comment: @Ramy:  Ignacio's snippet does it all in one nice line and seems to fit your code.